# Como converter um vetor de inteiro para uma variável apenas de inteiro?

Tags: c, array, cast

Preciso converter um vetor de inteiros para uma única variável, exemplo:

```
int teste[] = {2, 3, 5, 6};
```

para

```
int result = 2356;
```

como fazer isso? OBS: Não tenho o tamanho do vetor (+ - dinamico)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

descobri, funciona como matemática simples, onde a ultima posição do vetor é a unidade, a penultima a dezena e assim sucessivamente, como no caso acima:

```
teste[4] = teste[4]*1;
teste[3] = teste[3]*10;
teste[2] = teste[2]*100;
```

assim, basta criar um looping que atualiza esses valores para nós:

```
int numero = 0
for ( int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
         numero += teste[3-i] * powf(10, i);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Pegue o tamanho do array e divida pelo tamanho de um elemento para determinar a quantidade de elementos do array.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int teste[] = {2, 3, 5, 6};
    int i, num=0, tam;
    tam = (sizeof teste)/sizeof(int);
    for (i=0; i< tam; i++)
        num = num * 10 + teste[i];
    printf("\nNúmero: %d\n", num);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Uma alternativa seria transformar este vetor em uma *"string"* e depois passá-la para inteiro:

```
char retorno_vetor[tam];
int retorno;

int teste[] = {2, 3, 5, 6};
int tam = sizeof(vetor)/sizeof(int);

for (i=0 ; i<tam ; i++)
    retorno_vetor[i] = itoa(teste[i]);
retorno = atoi(retorno_vetor);
```

Comment: Sim, concordo, mas evitei utilizar este método pois após algumas pesquisas, fui informado que as funções itoa e atoi são um pouco problemáticas, logo não quis utilizá-las